# Problems with drop down menus over playing HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, css, html5-video, drop-down-menu

I'm having some issues getting a drop down menu (jQuery) to work on top of playing HTML 5 video. When the video hasn't started playing yet, like when one first loads the page, it's fine. However, once the video starts playing, and even after it gets paused, the drop down menus above the video start getting jumbled in Safari, and in Chrome, the text isn't there at all. In Firefox, the text displays as it should over playing video.

The code for the header is in a php file above an iframe, which is playing the video. So the header extends down through the iframe, while staying on top.

Here are some screenshots to see what I'm talking about (Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post the images directly but here are the links):

FIREFOX

http://oi41.tinypic.com/qpm16a.jpg

If you need to see the code, here's a link to the page where you can view the source:

http://filmlook.com/e_website/

(I couldn't post more links or images because of noob status, but you can check the site out for yourself to see what the problem is.)

Obviously, I'd like to keep the code mostly intact, but if there's another menu system I could use that could work better or any other options, I'll hear everything.

Also, I am kind of a noob with code, too, so please try and explain your answers as best you can.

Thanks

Comment: It looks fine in my firefox and chrome. I have IE8 and the menus appear behind the video. Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Hmm, OK. So it looks good on Windows then, it appears, except for the IE8 problem. With Chrome on Mac, the text disappears...

Comment: I can confirm that the problem exists in Mac Chrome & Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i change manually the css property "display: none;"  to "display: block"; it even works in chrome with the overlay. i see you are using an effet to show your dropdowns. have you tried it without that?

so just simply change your display and check if that works.

Comment: To confirm, are you talking about the display property of the #nav ul? I changed that to block, but then the submenus were being displayed as soon as the page loads, and not when you hover over them. That does seem to work in the sense that you could read the text over the playing video, though I'm still not sure how to get everything to work 100%. Could you please clarify which element to change the display for in the CSS?

Comment: i was talking about your ul elements which are in the li elements from your main navigation (ul id="nav"). since you are using an effect to show them (f.e. jquery onmouseover->fadein() ), i would try just to change the display element (f.e. jquery show() and hide()). just for checking if the problem still exists...because it works if i change that in firebug, so maybe a problem with the fadein/fadeout?!

i m more into mootools, but guess they have same functions.

Comment: so every ul > li > ul element has display:none; and a onmouseover->show() on mouseleave->hide()     try sth like this to check if that fixes the overlay bug

Comment: OK, so I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but in the header.php file, I changed the command for slideDown and slideUp to show and hide, respectively, and it worked! Thanks for your help.