# Fading Overlay To Video Tag Flickers In Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html5-video, flicker

I have a overlay that uses jQuery to fade in on top of a video tag. It works great in every other browser, but flickers in Internet Explorer 9 
Link to page: http://donahueweddingphotography.com/about

Answer (score 0):

here s another one with the same problem [Problems with drop down menus over playing HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421372/problems-with-drop-down-menus-over-playing-html5-video/9429868#9429868)

he didn t post a solution yet, but i gave him the advice to try, if it works without the fade effect. just to figur out where the real problem is. it could appear through the fade effect which usually changes several attributes like f.e. opacity

due i m working on mac, i don t have ie here to take a closer look. try to change the fade effects to show()/hide() and post if you still have the same problem.

Comment: Not really the same problem and fading is important

Comment: Very similar, but fading is required, but I made different changes to avoid frustration

Comment: ..seems like a bug. it worked for the other guy with removing the fade effect and just hide/show his overlays...